# Vimeo player iframe height

Tags: html, css, iframe, responsive-design, vimeo

I have a Vimeo player iframe on my website's homepage. My intention is have it at full width - edge to edge - in the browser window; while retaining the aspect ratio and avoiding black bars. So the video fills the most area.

I have this css applied to the vimeo player it:

```
.fluidVideoWrapper {
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20em;
  position: relative;
}

.fluidVideoWrapper iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

The `20em` is just so you guys can see it on the page. When I set the height to `100%` it disappears, the height seemingly becoming `0`.

An example of what I'm trying to attempt can be seen here, scroll down to the vimeo player: [vsco.co](http://vsco.co)

Can anyone suggest a fix for this?

Answer (score 3):

Try making the `.fluidVideoWrapper` container `position: absolute;` too and make the width and height of it 100%